# Не индексируются страницы

Tags: seo, индексация

Почему-то вхожу, смотрю статистику в яндекс вебмастере, там написано, что страниц в поиске 1, и в поиск почему-то попадает только главная страничка( Кто-нибудь знает из-за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причины могут быть разные. Из самых очевидных:

- сайт новый и бот еще просто не успел проиндескировать новые страницы,
- [robots.txt](http://robots.txt) запрещает индексирование сайта,
- на главной странице сайта нет ссылок на другие страницы, по которым бот может их найти,

Comment: Так сайтик далеко не новый и я давно его уже зарегал в яндексе, robots.txt нету, на главной есть все ссылки.